# Longest time possible that red delayed message stays on adsense performance tab

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

It seems that every time I make a significant enough change to my website, I get this message in red when I check the performance section of my adsense account:

"We're sorry, some data in this report is delayed, please try again later. There's no impact to ad serving or payments."

Sometimes I feel as if the move I made to my site was a huge mistake but at the same time, maybe google is just ridiculously slow.

What is the longest time I should wait for google to remove that message before I should suspect that (possibly google believes that) I made a major error on my site (for example: policy violation)?

I'd love to get info from google, but they won't give me any contact info or anything to speak to one of their agents.

Comment: I found notices to be kinda slow to go away in Adsense. I do not know your specific message. It has been quite a while, but I am thinking 3-4 weeks.